# Work around for session for signalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, signalr

I have been looking online and have been reading that you cant use `HttpContext.Current.Cache` in a signalR hub class, so what would be the workaround if i wanted to be able to have each user have some cache data that is accessed in my hub methods.

EDIT:

This data would only need to be used inside my hub class, I would not need to access it elsewhere in my asp.net application.  It would definitely need to be user specific though.

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to share this same exact cache with your ASP.NET application?

Comment: @DrewMarsh No, it would only need to be accessed inside the hub class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're only looking for the equivalent capabilities of the built in ASP.NET cache then you can simply spin up a static instance of [`System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) class. Then just access the static instance in your various hub methods.

Keep in mind this is a single server, in-memory solution. For more advanced, out of process, distributed caching solutions I would look to AppFabric (Azure or on-premises) or Memcached.

Comment: Wow, great answer! I was wondering what if you inject an instance of a class that maintains your cache, would that work?

Comment: Oh, of course injection would work great... and be a lot better of an implementation. I was just giving bare bones suggestion of a static cause I didn't want to assume anything about your setup. If you're going to go the injection route I would suggest creating a separate interface altogether to abstract the cache implementation so that you could later introduce a different backing implementation that does use a more powerful distributed cache technology.